# How to capture stdout and stderr both in one variable in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have tried so many things suggested in many discussions across SO and other sites to no avail. Here is my command that I am trying to capture full output of in a variable.

`Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri http://www.google.com`

Here is how I tried doing it (one of the many ways)

`$output1 = & Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri http://www.google.com 2>&1`

It continues to show the stderr output in the console and captures nothing in the variable. I have  also tried `Out-String` and `Tee-Object`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) call emits is **a statement-*terminating* error**, which **cannot be captured with `2>`redirections**.

- `2>` only works with *non-terminating* PowerShell errors and *stderr* output from external programs.

**To catch *terminating* errors** you need a **[`try { ... } catch { .. . }` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finall)**:

```
$output1 = 
  try   { Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri http://www.google.com } 
  catch { $_ }
```

- Inside the `catch` block, the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) contains the [`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) describing the terminating error that occurred.
- By implicitly *outputting* it, it is sent to PowerShell's *success* [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection), and therefore stored in variable `$output1`.

  - More typically, you'd choose to *display* the error (e.g. with `$_ | Write-Error`, which emits it as a *non-terminating* one)  or re-throw it with [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Throw), in which case the *statement*-terminating error turns into a *script*-terminating (thread-terminating) one.

For a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's surprisingly complex error handling, see [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).